# How to set custom request header keys with curl and PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl and php to upload file. I need help to set a custom request header keys like

```
X-Filename  blahblah.zip
X-Filesize  2677
X-Filetype  application/zip
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You must use the [**`curl_setopt()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function, and its **`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`** option (quoting) :

> An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format
>   `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`

Basically, in your case, you'd have something like this :

```
$headers = array(
    'X-Filename: blahblah.zip', 
    'X-Filesize: 2677', 
    'X-Filetype: application/zip', 
);
curl_setopt($your_resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: Does this overwrite the currently set headers, or merge into the existing headers?

Comment: It does overwrite, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Filename: blahblah.zip', 'X-Filesize: 2677', 'X-Filetype: application/zip'));
```