# Open URL with Authorization header with PHP

Tags: php

I have a URL that if I add an Authorization key in the headers,it shows me a payment page

I have to open this URL with PHP only.

How do I add the header key and echo the page content after I open it?

I tried to use CURL and file_get_contents but neither is working.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom request header keys with curl and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805656/how-to-set-custom-request-header-keys-with-curl-and-php)

Comment: Edited grammar, clarified title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a sophisticated library to do that, like guzzle:

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

you can set headers like this :

// Set various headers on a request

```
$client->request('GET', '/get', [
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
        'Accept'     => 'application/json',
        'X-Foo'      => ['Bar', 'Baz']
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`curl_setopt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) a la [How to set custom request header keys with curl and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805656/how-to-set-custom-request-header-keys-with-curl-and-php)